# mongoose seletion dats return all object not selection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I need to select a range of times un result of mongoose find. but return all the object.

```js
emonDb.find( { 'datas.power1.t' : {
      $gte: new Date('2020-11-26T22:00:00.000Z'),
      $lte: new Date('2020-11-27T16:00:00.000Z')
      }
    }).then((rs) =>{
      console.log('selection ......................')
      
      console.log(rs[0].datas)
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: power1: [
    { t: 2020-11-26T22:00:00.000Z, v: 4.554326501340498 },
    { t: 2020-11-27T00:00:00.000Z, v: 4.499140501354861 },
    { t: 2020-11-27T02:00:00.000Z, v: 4.498481683876175 },
    { t: 2020-11-27T04:00:00.000Z, v: 4.399432015881314 },...
// model 
        }],
        power1:[{
            _id : false,
            t: {
                type : Date
            },
            v: {
                type : Number
            },
        }
        ]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? By what you are saying I guess you want it to return just a field of the object, am I right? which one?

Comment: You want only specific fields to be returned?

Comment: I want return all the values between the 2 dates. I'm new in mongoose and i thing I mix mongodb and mongoose methods. It's not realy clear for me. thank you for help.

Comment: No problem for the projection, or the processing of the result but the query does not work and returns all the 't' values to me and not the selection.